# i get an error when i try to load the dataTable again ..VM127:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function at getauctionitems

Tags: php, html, jquery

i get an error when i try to load the dataTable again,when i click at first,it loads nicely but when i load another page and try to load the dataTable again i gain an error and the table fails to load..

> ..VM127:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function at getauctionitems

my codes

```
 <table id="listtables"  class="w3-table-all">
 
         <thead>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Auction Number</th>
            <th>Auction Time</th>
            <th>Sale Name</th>
             <th>Region</th>
             <th>Sale Type</th>
             <th>Auction Date</th>
             <th>Status</th>
             <th>Auction Name</th>
        </tr>
            
         </thead>
         
      </table>
 getauctionitems();
   
    
   function getauctionitems () {
        var date = new Date();
        var dateString = new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 )).toISOString().split("T")[0];
           
         var today = new Date();
         var todays = today.toLocaleTimeString();
         var h = today.getHours();
         var m = today.getMinutes();
    
         h = checkTime(h);
         m = checkTime(m);
    
        var ctime = h + ":" + m;
   
    ///    console.log(ctime);
   
        function checkTime(i) {
           return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
        }

         $('#listtables').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "retrieve": true,
            "destroy": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: "serverside/list.php", // json datasource
                "data": {
                    "cdate": dateString,
                    "curtime":ctime
                 },
                type: 'post',  // method  , by default get
            },
               "columns": [
                {data:null,
                    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                      return '<input type="checkbox" >';
                   }
                },
                 {data: 'auctionid',
                   'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                   $(td).attr('id', 'auctionidd');
             //    $(td).css('display','none');
                  } 
                },
                 {data: 'time',
                   'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                   $(td).attr('id', 'scheduletimeid');
               ///   $(td).css('display','none');
                  } 
                },
                {data: 'locationn',
                   'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                   $(td).attr('id', 'locationnid'); 
                  } 
                },
                {data: 'regionn',
                      'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                       $(td).attr('id', 'scheduleregionid'); 
                 } 
                 },
                {data: 'comp',
                    'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                        $(td).attr('id', 'companyid'); 
                } 
                },
                {data: 'auctionndate',
                    'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                     $(td).attr('id', 'currentdateid'); 
                     $(td).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                  }
                }    
                ,
                {data: 'date',
                    'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                     $(td).attr('id', 'statusid'); 
                     $(td).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                  }
                }    
                , 
                 {data: 'name',
                    'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                        $(td).attr('id', 'nameid'); 
                } 
                },
           ]
        });  
   }
```